# Normal derivate

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I want to prove:
If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$ is the normal derivate of a homogeneus polynomial $f$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}=f\deg f$,

but I have not an idea how to start!

Comment: What is the $n$ that you are talking about?

Comment: The $n$ is the derivative taken in the direction normal.If the normal direction is denoted by $n$ , then the directional derivative of a function f is sometimes denoted as $\frac {\partial f}{\partial n}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler's_homogeneous_function_theorem

Comment: Thank you very much!